# Pandas full outer index join with NaN for non-matching indexes

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

Trying to do a full outer join on these two Pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,1], 'b': [1,1,2], 'c': [1,2,3]}).set_index(['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'd': [11,12,13]}).set_index(['a'])

>>> df1
     c
a b   
1 1  1
2 1  2
1 2  3

>>> df2
    d
a    
1  11
2  12
3  13
```

I proceed to merge these two like this:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

     c   d
a b       
1 1  1  11
2 1  2  12
1 2  3  11
```

While I expect that also the non-matching indexes should be returned in this join, like so:

```
       c    d
a b       
1 1    1    11
2 1    2    12
3 NaN  NaN  13
1 2    4    11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a small trick - [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) by level `b`, `merge` and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by `b`:

```
df2 = df1.reset_index(level='b')
         .merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
         .set_index('b', append=True)
print (df2)
         c   d
a b           
1 1.0  1.0  11
  2.0  3.0  11
2 1.0  2.0  12
3 NaN  NaN  13
```

Comment: This seems to yield suffixed columns due to the overlap?

Comment: Interesting, for me in python 3, pandas 0.19.2 it works perfectly.

Comment: Indeed interesting — it works for me on `Python 3 + Pandas 0.19.2` as well, but not `Python 2.7 +  Pandas 0.19.2`.

Comment: maybe worse support `python 2.7` in pandas :(

Comment: sorry, probably `PEBKAC`, seems to work on `2.7` as well

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for, since this is not just a join but a MultiIndex join.

```
pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(),on='a', how='outer').set_index(['a','b'])

         c   d
a b           
1 1.0  1.0  11
  2.0  3.0  11
2 1.0  2.0  12
3 NaN  NaN  13
```

Its the same output but the index is ordered in this case.

Comment: So more or less: remove the indexes first, then merge? :-)

Comment: pretty much, and then set them back at the end